# Storing and Acaling images in Delphi xe7 Android

Tags: android, image, delphi, resources, scale

I've made a solution in my program, but now i have some doubts about it, but in order. I want to have buttons with pictures in my app, for that :

1) I've add 256x256 *.png images in resources and images, using type RCDATA (saw it in video example)

2) On form.create I use next functions before loading resources:

```
function Getscreenscale : Single;
var
   ScreenService: IFMXScreenService;
begin
   Result := 1;
   if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService (IFMXScreenService, IInterface(ScreenService)) then
   begin
      Result := ScreenService.GetScreenScale;
   end;
end;

Function GetscreenWidth : Single;
var
   ScreenService: IFMXScreenService;
begin
   Result := 1;
   if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService (IFMXScreenService, IInterface(ScreenService)) then
   begin
      Result := ScreenService.GetScreenSize.X;
   end;
end;

Function GetscreenHeight : Single;
var
   ScreenService: IFMXScreenService;
begin
   Result := 1;
   if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService (IFMXScreenService, IInterface(ScreenService)) then
   begin
      Result := ScreenService.GetScreenSize.Y;
   end;
end;
```

3) After that i set buttonsize (with images). Use minvalue to be independent from screen orientation

```
  minimvalue := Min(height,width);
  buttonsizex:= trunc(minimvalue / 10);
```

4) And then I load pictures, which have auto-size

```
Stream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'Picname', RT_RCDATA);
  Form1.frame81.image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(stream);
Stream.Free;
```

I'm a "newby" and can't understand is it alright or I'm doing big mistakes here?

Comment: Did you try to run this, at all? If yes, what is the outcome? Which version of Delphi are you using? Is `Image1` of `TImage` type? Why are you setting the buton size ten times smaller that the image size (BTW it would be better to use `ButtonSizeX := MinImValue div 10;`)?

Comment: div 10 not working in Delphi xe 7.

Comment: Well, today google play noticed me that my app is not adapted for 10' pads, my scaling is wrong :(, it's all working on my 2  10' devices

Comment: What do you mean `div 10` not working?